# What is the most pratical way to add comments to a method param with a existing variable

Tags: c#

It is a long title, but i'll explain it a bit wider here

So i have a file with a variable which has as xml comment

```
/// <summary>
/// A foo string in the file.
/// </summary>
Public string Foo;
```

And in the constructor i add an parameter

```
Public Main(string foo)
{
 this.Foo = foo;
}
```

Now i want to add xml comments to the constructor, where the param of foo contains the comment of the foo variable.

```
/// <summary>
/// The constructor of this file.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="foo"> 
* The content comment of the foo variable in this file *
</param>
Public Main(string foo)
{
 this.Foo = foo;
}
```

I've already tried to:

```
/// <summary>
/// The constructor of this file.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="foo"><see="Foo"></param>
Public Main(string foo)
{
 this.Foo = foo;
}
```

Or:

```
/// <summary>
/// The constructor of this file.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="foo"><seealso="Foo"></param>
Public Main(string foo)
{
 this.Foo = foo;
}
```

And even:

```
    /// <summary>
/// The constructor of this file.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="foo"><inheritdoc cref="Foo"/></param>
Public Main(string foo)
{
 this.Foo = foo;
}
```

Has someone else had the same problem encountered and how do i solve this.

This is what i want as a result when i hover my mouse over the param variable:

> (field) string Main.Foo
>
> A foo string in the file.

And not:

> (field) string Main.Foo

Comment: i think that is not possible

Comment: why such complicated comments? if you use Foo in Main VS shows a reference so u dont mess up the code with lines of unreadable comments

Comment: `<param name="foo">Value for the <see cref="Foo" /> field</param>`?

Comment: @Christian So the additional comment inside the constructor is unnessesarly if the param variable is going to declare itself to the file variable?